# How to get all the static pixels in a numpy array of shape (T, H, W, C)?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get an image of all static pixels across a numpy array of shape (T, H, W, C) where T is the temporal value, H is height, W is width and C is channel.
Currently my approach is as follows:

```
mask_static = cv2.bitwise_and(array[0], array[1])
for image in array[2:]:
   mask_static = cv2.bitwise_and(mask_static, image)

return mask_static
```

The issue with this approach is that if there are minimal changes in the values, the pixels still appear in the final mask. Is there a way of quickly checking that pixel value at position [i,j] is equal in all T's?

Thanks!

Note: I am not trying to do background extraction and I am well aware of openCV2's functions for foreground masking but this isn't what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the pixel values differences are below a given threshold from one image to the next, and update the mask in consequence.

I used a threshold if you are working with float values which can be suffer from the machine precision.

Here I used the 1-norm to compare pairs of pixels with C values each (namely the sum of the absolute differences of the given pixel channels), but you can compare eachpair of pixel as you wish

```
mask = np.ones_like(array[0,:,:,0], dtype = bool) # Mask of shape (H, W)
eps = 1e-8 # threshold to consider 2 pixels equal

for i in range(len(array) -1):
    mask = mask & (np.linalg.norm(array[i] - array[i+1], ord = 1, axis = 2) < eps) #logic AND with the next similar pixels locations
```

Adding the one line version of it if it is useful for anyone:

```
eps = 1e-8
mask = np.logical_and(*[np.linalg.norm(array[i] - array[i+1], ord = 1, axis = 2) < eps  for i in range(len(array) -1) ])
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your answer? Does this ensure that a pixel value is equal across all frames? Finally, why does setting eps = 0 create a black image if those pixels are 100% fixed?

Comment: Sure ! This considers two pixels are equal if the difference of the value summed over all the channels are below eps. I used eps in case you work with non integer values. If 2 pixel  at the same locations are (r1, g1, b1) and (r2, g2, b2), they are the same if |r1-r2| + |g1 + g2| + |b1-b2| < eps.  Here it compares each image to the next one in time. If you take eps = 0, you are being very strict so the values much match exactly.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working properly and I'm getting worse results than my current approach. How would I modify to check across all images instead of consecutive ones? Let's simplify the problem at look at (T, H, W)

Comment: What are your images value type ? floats between 0 and 1 or 0 to 255 int ?

Comment: My pixel values are uint8 255

Comment: Can you try with several reasonable values for `eps` like 5, 10, 20, 30 ? I tried with 3 simple images done manualy and it seems to work on these for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248552/discussion-between-cyril-and-plainravioli).